# Keep .NET core web app running on kestrel in production

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm hosting a web app on an EC2 instance in AWS. I will have nginx or an ELB in front of my web server, but on the web server itself the .net core app will be running on kestrel with `dotnet Mywebsite.dll`, if I understand correctly.

Whats the best way to keep this process running, and to automatically restart it is something goes wrong and to automatically start it up on reboot?

I'm currently trying to use supervisor to manage it but its adding a fair bit of complexity just getting it all up and running on a Amazon AMI.

Is there not a built in mechanism? How do you run your .net core web apps on linux in prod?

Comment: Use whatever suits your needs, cronjob checking if the process runs, docker orchestration tools, debian/ubuntu's systemd, windows service (if hosting on windows). Essentially you use the same tools for every other application that needs to run as a service and restart when it crashes

Comment: Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction?tabs=aspnetcore2x#monitoring-our-application except dont use ngnix/apache. `Restart=always` in particular will restart it as soon as it crashes.